# Check if field is null or blank before closing form on Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've been playing around this with VBA code to check if the field is empty before closing the form. If the field is empty, I want it to display a Yes/No message box. 
The issue that I'm having is that when I click `No` after the message appears (if the field is blank), it continues to close the form. Instead, when I click `No`, I want the focus to set on the field that needs to be addressed.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Close_Click()

If IsNull(cboTxtBx) Then
        MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "X is Blank!")
        If vbYes Then
            DoCmd.Close
        Else
            cboTxtBx.SetFocus
        End If
Else
    DoCmd.Close
End If

End Sub
```

I've also replaced `IsNull()` with `Len(cboTxtBx.value & "") = 0` and still have the same issue.
I've also removed the last `DoCmd.Close` statement but the form still closes once I hit `No`.

I'm sure the solution lies within the sequence of my code but I'm not proficient with VBA and I'm struggling to get this code to work.

One small note, `cboTxtBx` is a combo box. Not sure if that interrupts the code in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you answer the message box its result is interpreted nowhere, so the code goes on.

You would have to use it like this to really check the result of the message box:

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "X is Blank!") = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.Close
Else
    cboTxtBx.SetFocus
End If
```

Comment: Ah, I figured the solution was simple. This ended up working for me based on your feedback (thanks!):                

   

`Private Sub Close_Click()

If IsNull(cboTxtBx) Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "X is Blank!") = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.Close
        Else
            cboTxtBx.SetFocus
        End If
Else
    DoCmd.Close
End If

End Sub`

Comment: @aquadratic: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.